# set LanguageID of powerpoint presentation

Tags: c#, .net, com, powerpoint-2010

I want to set the LanguageId property of a Powerpoint Presentation, i know that I can access the LanguageId property of the individual slide like this

```
Slides[].Shapes[].TextFrame2.TextRange.LanguageID
```

and set them using a foreach loop.

But, what if I want to set the LanguageId property at the commencement of Powerpoint Application, at the presentation level. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it...

```
Presentation.DefaultLaguageID
```