# Set Proofing Language for powerpoint

Tags: c#, .net, com, vsto, powerpoint

I want to set the proofing language for a presentation.

```
Slides[].Shapes[].TextFrame2.TextRange.LanguageID  = lang;
```

This is to set the text frames in the slides. But, what if I want to set the proofing language at the start of a presentation?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [set LanguageID of powerpoint presentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389899/set-languageid-of-powerpoint-presentation)

Answer (score 1):

To set the default language of a presentation, use ActivePresentation.DefaultLanguageID. It works both in VBA and other languages.

To change the language on all shapes you need to make sure that you loop through grouped shapes as well.

If you need a Add-in for PowerPoint to set the proofing language for the entire presentation, you can find one here:
[Change Proofing language for an entire PowerPoint presentation](https://www.coragi.com/tips-and-tricks/microsoft-powerpoint/powerpoint-change-proofing-language-for-entire-presentation/)

Answer (score 0):

Use ActivePresentation.DefaultLanguageID